# Filter array of objects using arrays of values?

Tags: javascript

Given the following array of objects:

```
var data = [
  {fruit: "apples", stock: false, season: true},
  {fruit: "peaches", stock: true, season: false},
  {fruit: "oranges", stock: false, season: false},
  {fruit: "pears", stock: false, season: true},
]
```

and these two arrays:

```
var fruits = ["apples", "peaches"]
var inv = ["stock"]
```

How can I filter the objects, from `data`, so that objects are kept:

- if they have a `fruit` in the `fruits` array; AND
- they have a property from the `inv` array which is set to true

So, in the above example, only peaches survive:

```
  var result = [
    {fruit: "peaches", stock: true, season: false}
  ]
```

Comment: The simplest approach would be three loops, hence... What have you tried so far?

Comment: what means "*they have a property from the `inv` array which is set to true*"? does a single property has to be set to `true`, or if more all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can just use filter with [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```js
var data = [
  {fruit: "apples", stock: false, season: true},
  {fruit: "peaches", stock: true, season: false},
  {fruit: "oranges", stock: false, season: false},
  {fruit: "pears", stock: false, season: true},
]

var fruits = ["apples", "peaches"]
var inv = ["stock"]

let filtered = data.filter(item => 
    fruits.includes(item.fruit) && inv.some(i => item[i]))

console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could filter by looking in the fruits array with [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) and check the property by iterating `inv` with [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

```js
var data = [ { fruit: "apples", stock: false, season: true }, { fruit: "peaches", stock: true, season: false }, { fruit: "oranges", stock: false, season: false }, { fruit: "pears", stock: false, season: true }],
    fruits = ["apples", "peaches"],
    inv = ["stock"],
    result = data.filter(o => fruits.includes(o.fruit) && inv.every(k => o[k]));
   
console.log(result);
```

Comment: It seems your should use `some` instead of the `every`: "they have _a property_ from the `inv` array which is set to true".

Comment: this part is questionable.

Comment: Not a big deal anyways. OP can swap the methods according to his/her needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use combination of [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) here.

```js
var data = [
  {fruit: "apples", stock: false, season: true},
  {fruit: "peaches", stock: true, season: false},
  {fruit: "oranges", stock: false, season: false},
  {fruit: "pears", stock: false, season: true},
]

var fruits = ["apples", "peaches"]
var inv = ["stock"]

var result= data.filter(a=> fruits.some(b=> b == a.fruit) && inv.every(k => a[k]));
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var output = data.filter(val => {
    if (fruits.includes(val.fruit)) {
        return inv.filter(prop => {
            if (val[prop] == true)
                return val
        }).length > 0
    }
})
console.log(output)
```

I think this will do, if you just want to filter through.